# How skinny should controllers be, how fat should models be in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mvc

I know it's a good idea to put all data-related logic in your models in CakePHP, but what would you say about keeping every Model::find() and its particular params in the model? Is this good practice, or just taking things too far?

**For example, is this:**

PostsController:

```
function index() {
    $posts = $this->Post->getLatest();
    $this->set(compact('posts'));
}
```

Post model:

```
function getLatest() {
    $params = array(
        'conditions' => array('published' => 1),
        'limit' => 5,
        'order' => 'publish_date DESC'
    );
    return $this->find('all', $params);
}
```

**Better than this:**

PostsController:

```
function index() {
    $params = array(
        'conditions' => array('published' => 1),
        'limit' => 5,
        'order' => 'publish_date DESC'
    );
    $posts = $this->Post->find('all', $params);
    $this->set(compact('posts'));
}
```

Any thoughts? Which is better architecturally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's totally egilable to write shorthand-`find` functions. This way the controller is not depended of the model's parameters. I tend to go that far, that I don't use any fields directly in my controllers (and thus, not using `find` in controllers at all).
You could save a variable by defining the array in your find-call aswell ;).

Comment: Thanks for that. I use the first example I gave (all params in the model) because I feel it scans better and opens more opportunities for model method reuse. I just had a slight nagging doubt that I'm going overboard with it, so I appreciate the feedback. Seeing as nobody else has written otherwise, I reckon it must not be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but i thought i'd share my experience.

I recently had an application where i was sick of defining all the Contain associations every time i wanted to get an a record. So i created an `Application::getApplication($id);` method that included all my Contains and their conditions.

This worked great, every time i wanted an application i just called this. unfortunately when i moved to production and had to deal with a lot more data this became too slow to use in a lot of places. I had to go back and change all the calls to `getApplicaion()` to usual finds where i could tweak the Contains parameter to only get what i needed.